# Live usb problem

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

Recently I created a live Ubuntu USB (using Universal USB Installer). When I booted my computer using the USB (my computer has no operating system installed by the way) I checked my installation media for errors and two were detected. My question is, how do I fix these errors?

Comment: The USB has the errors due to a faulty installation of Ubunbtu I presume. Should I re-install Ubuntu on my usb or is there a better/easier way to fix the problem?

Comment: We can't help you fix something when we don't know what really broken...edit your question and include the error messages first. Otherwise this will be flagged as unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, **there is no way to fix this problem** without rewriting the USB

There can be two reasons for this kind of errors:

**First:** The downloaded ISO may be corrupted. This can happen if there is a glitch during download. First, determine if the ISO file you downloaded got corrupted during download. You do this by checking the MD5SUM of the ISO file. See [Ubuntu Hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) for the correct MD5SUM and [How To MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) for how to check.

If the MD5SUM is wrong, download again and check again. Repeat until you get the correct MD5SUM.

**Second:** The USB drive may have some bad sectors. If this is the case, format the USB stick FAT32, and check for bad sectors again. Formatting the drive usually excludes the bad sectors. However, if this does not work, throw the USB in the trash and get a new one.

**Finally,** recreate the Live USB using the *Universal USB Installer* as before.

Hop this helps